# is there a better way to theme edit node form instad of theme_ each element for drupal 6?

Tags: drupal, themes

d6 there is no module that i just can change the variables like $mycckfied[options]=array() or unset($title);

its mass to do each field type a theme function and hack it by mytheme_options or whatever...

Answer (score 0):

[hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) - will allow you to make a great number of changes to the form before it's sent to the theme layer.  [Here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/group/form_api/7) is more info on how form generation works in Drupal, and how you can modify the output of forms.